# Redirecting stdout to socket

Tags: c, sockets, stdout, stdio, dup2

I am trying to redirect stdout to a socket. I do something like this:

```
dup2(new_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

After doing so all `stdio` functions writing to the stdout fail. I have tried to reopen stdout this way:

```
fclose(stdout);
stdout = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "wb");
```

But `printf` and other functions still don't work.

EDIT:

I am affraid that I misunderstood the problem at the first place. After some more debugging I've figured out that this is a real issue:

```
printf("Test"); // We get Broken pipe here
// Reconnect new_fd
dup2(new_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
printf("Test"); // This also returns Broken pipe despite that stdout is fine now
```

Thanks.

Comment: `fdopen` only wraps an existing file descriptor.  When you call `fclose`, you close `stdout` and remove fd 1 as a valid file descriptor.

Comment: It doesn't work even without `fclose`. After preforming `dup2` printf fails but I can still do `write()` to `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: Because you've duplicated `new_fd` over `STDOUT_FILENO`, you'll need to close it and reopen.  What operating system are you on?

Comment: I use FreeBSD. Yeah, I've duplicated `new_fd` over `STDOUT_FILENO` because I want to redirect stdout to the new_fd.

Comment: Sorry, I had some errors below.  Try it now (using "/dev/tty" instead of "/dev/stdout").

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by clearing a stdio's error indicator after fixing `stdout`:

```
clearerr(stdout);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1: on `dup2(src, dst)`

A number of operating systems track open files through the use of file descriptors.  `dup2` internally duplicates a file descriptor from the `src` to `dst`, closing `dst` if its already open.

What your first statement is doing is making every write to `STDOUT_FILENO` to go to the object represented by `new_fd`.  I say object because it could be a socket as well as a file.

I don't see anything wrong with your first line of code, but I don't know how `new_fd` is defined.

2: on reopening `stdout`

When you close a file descriptor, the OS removes it from its table.  However, when you open a file descriptor, the OS sets the smallest available file descriptor as the returned value.  Thus, to reopen `stdout`, all you need to do is reopen the device.  I believe the device changes depending on the OS.  For example, on my Mac the device is `/dev/tty`.

Therefore, to reopen the stdout, you want to do the following:

```
close(1);
open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I don't want to reopen stdout. I want to redirect stdout to a socket.